# Hangman loop, letter issue C#

Tags: c#

Hej, does anyone know how i can make my method for guessing letters remember 
the guesses before? Currently it turns all the "right" guesses into the last right letter guessed :(

```
public void myGuess(char letter)
{
    string wordToGuess = label4.Text;
    string wordToShow = label5.Text;

    for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.Length; i++)
    {
        if (wordToGuess[i] == letter || wordToGuess[i] == wordToShow[i])
            wordToShow = wordToShow.Remove(i, 1).Insert(i, Char.ToString(letter)); 
    }

    label5.Text = wordToShow;

    if (wordToGuess == wordToShow) 
        this.Close();

    Form Win = new Win();
    Win.Show();
}
```

Comment: Which variable stored the right guesses?

Comment: @Tijesunimi: None... that is what the OP is asking for help with

Comment: @musefan Thanks. I guess I misunderstood this `Right now it turns all the "right" guesses into the last right letter guessed`. It sounded more like the OP already had a way of storing right guesses

Comment: @Tijesunimi: Confused me too, but I think they are referring to how they check the current word... I could be wrong

Comment: @Tijesunimi I don't know how to store the right guesses! The first guess works but the 2nd and 3rd... for example: the word is DATA --> _ _ _ _ the first guess is A --> _A_A, the second guess is D --> DD_D.. Any idés for how to make it store the right guesses?

Comment: @Cartho12 get rid of the `|| wordToGuess[i] == wordToShow[i]` or replace the insert with `.Insert(i,Char.ToString(wordToShow[i]))`

Comment: @BobVale Thank you! I understood that it was what was wrong but I didnät knew how to make it right ;)

Comment: @Cartho12 I've posted an answer for you based on this then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your loop.

Your test checks if the character equals either the guessed letter or the letter at the same position in the already guessed words.

If the test succeeds you then effectively replace the value with the guessed letter.

You need to either remove the second part of the test:

```
if (wordToGuess[i] == letter)
        wordToShow = wordToShow.Remove(i, 1).Insert(i, Char.ToString(letter));
```

or change the replacement

```
if (wordToGuess[i] == letter || wordToGuess[i] == wordToShow[i])
        wordToShow = wordToShow.Remove(i, 1).Insert(i, Char.ToString(wordToShow[i]));
```

Also instead of removing/inserting if you change the wordToShow to a char array first you can then just directly change it's value and convert back to a string when finished, this makes the code a little easier to read. It may also be better performance than all the insert/removes.

```
var newWord = wordToShow.ToCharArray();
for (var i = 0; i<wordToGuess.Length; i++) {
   if (wordToGuess[i] == letter) {
     newWord[i] = letter;
   }
}
wordToGuess = new string(newWord);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a global list of char and add to it after every guess

```
List<char> guesses = new List<char>();
```

Then in your method just add to it

```
guesses.Add(letter);
```

and then you can check using this

```
if (guesses.Contains(letter))
{
    //DoSomething
}
```

Comment: ..and how to check if a letter is in the list?

Comment: does it have to be global? A contentious issue sir! I would have prefer _accessible_ intead.

Comment: @Gusdor Indeed! I have no clue as to the program structure so I went with what should almost always work.